# urllib.request in Python 3 - check if file is downloadable

Tags: python-3.x, http, download, urllib, urlretrieve

In Python 3.8.2 I download files with:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_address, file_name)
```

How can I check if file on url_address is downloadable without downloading it?
I tried with **try** statement. It only raises Error when it can't download files, but it always downloads when the file from a given URL address is downloadable.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this with. It prints "content-type" attribute from http header.

```
try:
    site = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    header = site.info()
    print(header["content-type"])
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

and then I download as always:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_name)
```